# Magento how can I change qty value on site view?

Tags: magento

I create 4 sites on magento. In this sites some products are same, but they must to have different qty value on site view. Qty is global attribute. How can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

You should create 4 separate products ( duplicate ) and make each visible only for one store. This can be done in `Catalog -> Product -> *choose your product* -> Websites tab`. Only then you can have different quantity for each store.

Comment: But in this case, I`ll have 4 different products.
What if I`ll create my attribute and use it like qty.
What I must do for this?

Comment: I need something like this but free.
http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_multi_location_inventory.html